# Configuring website to be private and a page public

Tags: apache

I'm using Apache in my web server which resides in a public IP.  I wan to be able to limit access of this whole site to the local network except for one file.
For example:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mysite">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.1/24
</Directory>
```

would limit access to my website only to the people in that IP range.  However, the file *myfile.html* also resides in that directory, and I want it to be visible publicly. Maybe:

```
<File "/var/www/mysite/myfile.html">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</File>
```

So my questions are: Does the `<File>` tag go inside the `<Directory>` tag or somewhere else? Will *myfile.html* be visible publicly even though it resides in a Directory that is only visible to a range of IPs?  Do the configurations above look right? (I'm an apache noob) Is there a better way to this (maybe the firewall)?

Your input is appreciated.

Comment: Have you just tried the above? Of course firewall/NAT/iptables is better way, or divide in to two sites/vhosts completely.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this because it is the production server and I'm currently building the development/testing server.  I truly don't think the file we'll be accessible if the directory in which it resides is not.  How could I tackle this with iptables?